# Prove that, for any vectors $x$ and $y$ we have that $x + (y - x) = y$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

I am currently studying *Introduction to Hilbert Spaces with Applications*, the third edition, by Debnath and Mikusinski. Chapter 1, exercise 2.(a), is as follows:

> Prove that, for any vectors $x$ and $y$ we have that $x + (y - x) = y$.

The definition of vector space is given as follows:

> By a vector space we mean a nonempty set $E$ with two operations:
>
> $(x, y) \mapsto x + y$ from $E \times E$ into $E$ called *addition*.
>
> $(\lambda, x) \mapsto \lambda x$ from $\mathbb{F} \times E$ into $E$ *multiplication* by scalars,
>
> such that the following conditions are satisfied for all $x, y, z \in E$ and $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{F}$:
>
> (a) $x + y = y + x$;
>
> (b) $(x + y) + z = x + (y + z)$
>
> (c) For every $x, y \in E$ there exists a $z \in E$ such that $x + z = y$;
>
> (d) $\alpha (\beta x) = (\alpha \beta) x$;
>
> (e) $(\alpha + \beta)x = \alpha x + \beta x$;
>
> (f) $\alpha(x + y) = \alpha x + \alpha y$
>
> (g) $1x = x$
>
> Elements of $E$ are called vectors. If $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{R}$, then $E$ is called a real vector space, and if $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{C}$, $E$ is called a complex vector space.

My proof proceeds as follows:

---

$$\begin{align} x + (y - x) &= x + (y + (-1)x) \\ &= (x + y) + (-1)x \\ &= (y + x) + (-1)x \\ &= y + (x + (-1)x) \\ &= y + x(1 - 1) \\ &= y + x(0) \end{align}$$

---

Since we haven't yet proven that $x(0) = 0$ (that is a later exercise), I'm unsure of how to proceed. I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to review my proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Page $3$ of the book:

> (1) The unique solution of $x+z=y$ is denoted by $y-x.$ According to the definition of the zero vector, we have $x-x=0.$ The vector $0-x$ is denoted by $-x.$
>
> (2) We use $0$ to denote both the scalar $0$ and the zero vector; this will not cause confusion.

So $$\begin{array}
&x+(y-x)&=(x+y)-x\qquad &\text{by (b)}\\
&=(y+x)-x\qquad &\text{by (a)}\\
&=y+(x-x)\qquad &\text{by (b)}\\
&=y+0 \qquad &\text{by (1)}\\
&=y. \qquad &\text{by (2)}\end{array}$$

Comment: Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

Third step from the last; $x+(-x)$ is $0$ from the additive inverse law and hence the result holds